# UWP Gridview binding to View Model

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview

I'm using a GridView in a UserControl to display a five by four square of graphical buttons that allow selection of a Lesson.

This is in a Windows 8.1 Store App that I'm upgrading to Windows 10 UWP.

I previously used Tap and Right-Tap actions to select a Lesson or activate the CommandBar to perform related actions for a Lesson through the SelectionChanged event.  However, there have been changes to how Interactions now work under Windows 10, I have been unable to get the Gridview to work at all with binding the SelectedItem to the selected LessonButton in the view model, nor the SelectionChanged and ItemClick events for such purposes.  The Gridview selections behaviour doesn't work, as once an item is selected it is never deselected.  So finally, I've taken a different tack and am trying Tap and Right-Tap events for the Gridview Items.  However the issue is, that no matter which way I approach it, I can't get Binding to work correctly.

So I have an object called LessonButton:

```
public class LessonButton : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //public LessonButton() { }
    public LessonButton(SolidColorBrush inBackground, bool inComplete, double inHeight, int inNumber, bool inSelected, bool inStarted,
        Status inState, double inWidth)
    {
        ...
        Started = inStarted;
        ...
    }
    ...
    private bool _started;
    public bool Started
    {
        get { return _started; }
        set { if (_started != value) { _started = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    }
    ...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

It is added to an observable collection in the View Model:

```
public class LessonsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<LessonButton> Lessons { get; } = new ObservableCollection<LessonButton>();

    private LessonButton _selectedLessonButton;

    public LessonButton SelectedLessonButton
    {
        get { return _selectedLessonButton; }
        set { if (_selectedLessonButton != value) { _selectedLessonButton = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In a user control I set the DataContext with:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <classes:LessonsViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

..and I then have a GridView defined as:

```
        <GridView x:Name="LessonGridView" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}"
              SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLessonButton, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Left" MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalChildrenAlignment="Top"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

With the GridView item format defined in a ControlTemplate as part of the GridViewItemStyle.

I've tried to access the LessonButton variables in various ways using Binding and xBind, but could only get the program to run with the ControlTemplate using this XAML:

```
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="{StaticResource BadgeSize}" 
    Height="{StaticResource BadgeSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Opacity="{Binding Started, Converter={StaticResource OpacityConverterTrueValueIsVisible}}"
    Source="/Assets/SelectionButtonGroup/square310x310logobw.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

The Converter simply returns a 1 or 0 depending upon the value of the bool Started.

Although this code work, it is not correct somehow and Visual Studio reports an unknown error and states it cannot find the Started property.  In fact it can't find any of the properties of LessonButton and I've been unable to find the correct syntax for exposing them, even with x:Bind code such as:

```
{x:Bind LessonViewModel.Lessons.LessonButton.Selected}
```

..or versions thereof, using casting etc.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, which reports the aforementioned errors and displays wavy lines over the entire ControlTemplate with an error where it cannot find another Converter artefact that isn't even related to this code.. which in itself, I find extremely irritating.  Is it me or does the XAML Intellisence in VS seem very flaky, in that it gives up and reports false errors if it can't identify the root cause of a real one?

Ideally I'd like the Gridview SelectedItem to bind with the ViewModel.  But even trying actions via Tap events I can't get the binding to correctly expose LessonButton properties in the ControlTemplate XAML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the  `ItemContainerStyle` to Bind your `LessonButton` variables to. The `ItemContainerStyle` is used to style the Item with selection marks, its hover and pressed states etc.

You should instead use a `DataTemplate` stored inside your `UserControl`'s resources like so:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="GridViewTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonName}">
    </DataTemplate>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <GridView x:Name="GridView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewTemplate}">
  </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Then give your `DataTemplate` a name (above "GridViewTemplate") and set it as the `ItemTemplate` of your `GridView`.

Comment: Hi jsmyth886,  Thanks for your quick response.  I adjusted the code as you suggested and created a new cut-down project with just the bear minimum.  Here's a link to the file I've shared from my Dropbox -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jq4126ca2e9gzuz/GridViewDebug.zip?dl=0

Comment: You can see that VS behaves as I described in that it will run fine, but the XAML Intellisense still reports that it can't find the Selected property. All my research points to the code being correct as it is, yet VS still reports an error.  Could this be a bug in VS?

Comment: @PythonesqueSpam very interesting I have no idea why intellisense shows so many errors yet still runs fine. Might be useful to post this on MSDN, see if you can get some help from Microsoft

Comment: At your suggestion, I've posted on MSDN -
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2532d561-6115-440b-8086-82aa85f0d53e/xaml-intellisense-detecting-false-errors
..hoping for an answer..